# Replace the array of elements using another array of elements if its have both common value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Below is the `referenceArray` to compare and manipulate `originalArray`

```
const referenceArray = [
                       { name: 'animal', source: ['duck', 'cat'], target: ['water', 'ground'] },
                       { name: 'car', source: ['tata', 'kia'], target: ['tiago', 'sector'] },
                       { name: 'bike', source: ['honda', 'hero'], target: ['livo', 'xtream'] },
                       { name: 'vehicle', source: ['honda', 'hero'], target: ['hard', 'soft'] },
                       ];
```

And this is I want to change the array `originalArray` source and target values with the help of `referenceArray` source and target
if it's matched take name value and set that value to `originalArray` source and target.

```
const originalArray = [
    { source: 'water', target: 'hero' },
    { source: 'tata', target: 'ground' },
    { source: 'livo', target: 'kia' },
    { source: 'hero', target: 'sector' },
  ];
```

Expected output that is required:

```
 const output1 = [
    { source: 'animal', target: ['bike', 'vehicle'] },
    { source: 'car', target: 'animal' },
    { source: 'bike', target: 'car' },
    { source: ['vehicle', 'bike'], target: 'car' },
  ];


 const output2 = [
    { source: 'animal', target: 'bike' },
    { source: 'animal', target: 'vehicle' },
    { source: 'car', target: 'animal' },
    { source: 'bike', target: 'car' },
    { source: 'vehicle', target: 'car' },
    { source: 'bike', target: 'car' },
  ];
```

Either output is acceptable, however `output2` is preferred.

I'm confused how to achieve this format without getting key value conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective (**Output-2**, from the question above).

**Code Snippet**

```js
// get output in format-2
const getOutput2 = (refArr, arr) => (
  arr.flatMap(        // iterate using ".flatMap" to avoid nested result
    ({ source : osrc, target : otgt }) => (
      refArr.filter(      // filter for "source" using ref-arr
        ob => ob?.source.includes(osrc) || ob?.target.includes(osrc)
      ).sort(             // sort descending to match order of output-2
        (a, b) => b.name > a.name ? 1 : -1
      ).flatMap(          // for each "source", iterate using ".flatMap"
        ob => refArr.filter(    // filter for "target" 
          ob2 => ob2?.source.includes(otgt) || ob2?.target.includes(otgt)
        ).sort(           // sort ascending to match order of output-2
          (a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1
        ).map(ob2 => ({         // construct the desired objective array
          source: ob.name, target: ob2.name
        }))
      )
    )
  )
);

// reference array from question
const referenceArray = [{
    name: 'animal',
    source: ['duck', 'cat'],
    target: ['water', 'ground']
  },
  {
    name: 'car',
    source: ['tata', 'kia'],
    target: ['tiago', 'sector']
  },
  {
    name: 'bike',
    source: ['honda', 'hero'],
    target: ['livo', 'xtream']
  },
  {
    name: 'vehicle',
    source: ['honda', 'hero'],
    target: ['hard', 'soft']
  },
];

// original array from question
const originalArray = [{
    source: 'water',
    target: 'hero'
  },
  {
    source: 'tata',
    target: 'ground'
  },
  {
    source: 'livo',
    target: 'kia'
  },
  {
    source: 'hero',
    target: 'sector'
  },
];

// log the results to console for verification
console.log(getOutput2(referenceArray, originalArray));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Explanation**

Comments added inline in the snippet above